# Using UNIQUE and TRANSPOSE in a single formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, unique, transpose, array-formulas

I want to create an array of values using the email address as the unique value.

**Scenario**:

Each eCommerce order create a new row in a spreadsheet:

1. The email of the user - user account
2. A unique ID of a product
3. Another unique ID of the product

In another sheet (or area), I want an array of data to show all product ID information for each user account. So If they purchase a product again, the data array simply updates the email line with the IDs. The IDs should be comma separated.

Thanks to [player0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0?tab=profile) for starting this!

Here's a spreadsheet to play with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TN9gk4mD9qXBBSd70SVvQlW5aMrQGEzDZe4kX2aGmGg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(UNIQUE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({A3:A, 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A3:A=TRANSPOSE(A3:A),   
 TRANSPOSE(B3:B)&",", )),,ROWS(A3:A))))&"|", ",|", ), 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A3:A=TRANSPOSE(A3:A),   
 TRANSPOSE(C3:C)&",", )),,ROWS(A3:A))))&"|", ",|", )}, COUNTA(A3:A), 3)), 
 ", ", ","))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks again! This is perfect